# Regression Tree Forest in Weka

Tags: data-mining, classification, weka, regression, random-forest

I'm using Weka and would like to perform regression with random forests. Specifically, I have a dataset:

```
Feature1,Feature2,...,FeatureN,Class
1.0,X,...,1.4,Good
1.2,Y,...,1.5,Good
1.2,F,...,1.6,Bad
1.1,R,...,1.5,Great
0.9,J,...,1.1,Horrible
0.5,K,...,1.5,Terrific
.
.
.
```

Rather than learning to predict the most likely class, I want to learn the probability distribution over the classes for a given feature vector. My intuition is that using just the RandomForest model in Weka would not be appropriate, since it would be attempting to minimize its absolute error (maximum likelihood) rather than its squared error (conditional probability distribution). Is that intuition right? Is there a better model to be using if I want to perform regression rather than classification?

**Edit:** I'm actually thinking now that in fact it may not be a problem. Presumably, classifiers are learning the conditional probability P(Class | Feature1,...,FeatureN) and the resulting classification is just finding the c in Class that maximizes that probability distribution. Therefore, a RandomForest classifier should be able to give me the conditional probability distribution. I just had to think about it some more. If that's wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to predict the probabilities for each class explicitly, you need different input data. That is, you would need to replace the value to predict. Instead of one data set with the class label, you would need n data sets (for n different labels) with aggregated data for each unique feature vector. Your data would look something like

```
Feature1,...,Good
1.0,...,0.5
0.3,...,1.0
```

and

```
Feature1,...,Bad
1.0,...,0.8
0.3,...,0.1
```

and so on. You would need to learn one model for each class and run them separately on any data to be classified. That is, for each label you learn a model to predict a number that is the probability of being in that class, given a feature vector.

If you don't need the probabilities to be predicted explicitly, have a look at the Bayesian classifiers in Weka, which make use of probabilities in the models that they learn.

Comment: So the difficulty here is that I don't have the actual distribution data that I'm trying to learn. Rather, I have samples from it. So if I separated every class into its own dataset, it would be a binary classification task. I suppose I could do that, but is there some principled reason why it would work better?

Comment: If you're predicting the probability, it becomes a regression task -- you predict a number instead of a label. The point of separating into several data sets would be to be able to judge for each class individually what the probability of data belonging to it is.